# setting firewall-cmd --permanent is not sticking after reboot

Tags: network-interface, firewall, interface, netplan

I have two network interfaces: eth0, and p2p1. My default zone is set to public. I would like to permanently set p2p1 to be trusted.

In order the achieve this I run:

```
sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --change-zone=p2p1 --zone=trusted
```

after that I get this:

```
The interface is under control of NetworkManager, setting zone to 'trusted'.
success
```

(I have **netplan** controlling my network.) To check if all is good I do:

```
sudo firewall-cmd --get-active-zones
public
  interfaces: eth0
trusted
  interfaces: p2p1
```

But after a reboot it is all gone. How can I make this stick?

**Update:** I found [this](https://www.certdepot.net/rhel7-get-started-firewalld/) "To permanently assign the *eth0* network interface to the internal zone (a file called internal.xml is created in the /etc/firewalld/zones directory... "

```
root@me:~# nmcli con show | grep p2p1
netplan-p2p1  44db1fb7-b83f-36aa-8dd1-faa6fb97f6c4  ethernet  p2p1   
p2p1          3ad65062-db85-4ba6-9104-76644e78a5c4  ethernet  --     
p2p1          c3297794-7641-4033-9f68-156f26ffe024  ethernet  --     
root@me:~# nmcli con mod "netplan-p2p1" connection.zone trusted
root@me:~# nmcli con up "netplan-p2p1"
Connection successfully activated (D-Bus active path: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/3)
```

... the above calls changed **p2p1** to zone=trusted. But same problem -- it is not sticking.

I am on an Ubuntu 18.10 system, so adding a config file like suggested [here](https://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?289546-Permanent-firewall-cmd-zone-home-change-interface-p2p1&p=1641312#post1641312) will not work. Not sure, but I am assuming I need to add some script in "/etc/network/if-up.d" folder.

**Update 2:** netplan config file 01-netcfg.yaml

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
  ethernets:
#   WAN
    eth0:
        dhcp4: no
        dhcp6: no
        addresses: [76.80.54.221/29]
        gateway4: 76.80.54.217
        nameservers:
            addresses: [209.18.47.61,209.18.47.62]
#   LAN
    p2p1:
        dhcp4: no
        dhcp6: no     
        addresses: [192.168.1.99/24]
        gateway4: 192.168.1.100
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out -- finally.

I added a script file `zone-for-p2p1` inside the directory `/etc/network/if-up.d`.

`zone-for-p2p1` script file content:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# sets zone for p2p1 adapter to "trusted"
# to find out adapter name run "nmcli con show | grep p2p1"
#
nmcli con mod "netplan-p2p1" connection.zone trusted
```

Then I also made sure the file has execution permission:

```
sudo chmod +x /etc/network/if-up.d/zone-for-p2p1
```

Now doing a reboot the script assigns the proper zone to the adapter. [This post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/332298/if-up-d-script-not-working) helped me add the script.

Answer (score 2):

Since your interface is controlled by `NetworkManager`, you can manipulate the connection settings directly using `nmcli` to permanently set the zone:

```
sudo nmcli connection modify p2p1 connection.zone trusted
```

The default behaviour for this command is to make the changes in a persistent manner, which will survive across a reboot.

Comment: I am using netplan but controlled by NetworkManager. (please see Update above.) Your suggested line did also not stick. I had to change your line to this: `sudo nmcli connection modify netplan-p2p1 connection.zone trusted`  so it would change the zone, but it too did no stick.

Comment: @MeSo2 Then the problem isn't one of persistence. Netplan is probably overwriting all of your settings on reboot. I'm not familiar with Netplan, but let me check the documentation and see if I can come up with an alternative.

Comment: That would be very much appreciated. I will add my netplan info above.

Comment: @MeSo2 So as far I understand, Netplan does not offer the functionality to directly set a parameter used by NetworkManager. Your best bet may be to file a bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/netplan

Comment: Thank you for looking into Netplan. I figured it out. I needed to add a script to the `/etc/network/if-up.d/` folder. Now it is working. Please Up-Vote my question and Answer - I need it. Thank you.

Comment: @MeSo2 Glad to know that you've found a solution. However, I believe NetworkManager is intended to replace the ifcfg-* scripts. In that sense, I think your approach might not be a canonical one.

Comment: I noticed that  ifcfg-* scripts ([like this](https://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?289546-Permanent-firewall-cmd-zone-home-change-interface-p2p1&p=1641312#post1641312)) are no longer supported, but placing a script inside the folder is.

Answer (score 1):

I've found a [blog post](https://blog.christophersmart.com/2014/01/15/add-permanent-rules-to-firewalld/) that seems related. Perhaps try to restart the firewall:

`systemctl restart firewalld.service`

This should be done after adding your rule and before rebooting.

Comment: I tried what you suggested: "Please note, if you use –permanent switch, the rule will be activate only _AFTER_ the firewall rules have been reloaded or firewalld.service has been restarted." --  but it is not working.

Comment: It looks like `change-zone` is not a command that -permanent will support based on this [post](https://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?289546-Permanent-firewall-cmd-zone-home-change-interface-p2p1&p=1640291#post1640291).

Answer (score 1):

Did you try reloading the firewall instead of restarting it? If not, you can do that as follows:

```
firewall-cmd --reload
```

In my experience, anytime you use the `--permanent` switch, you should apply that change using the `--reload` as stated above.

Comment: as stated [above](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/492124/setting-firewall-cmd-permanent-is-not-sticking-after-reboot/492150#comment903400_492134) in the link to the post `--permanent` switch will not work with a `--change-zone=p2p1` call. I tried your suggestion, but it too did not work/stick.

Comment: another [source](http://www.advancedclustering.com/act_kb/fixing-firewall-zones-centos-7-5/) that states the same/related problem

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution for the **Ubuntu 18.04** with a **if-up** script and **firewall-cmd** tool (*nmcli doesn't work for some reason*)

1. Become a root and create an if-up file with executive permission

   ```
   sudo su -
   touch /etc/network/if-up.d/p2p1-trusted && chmod +x $_
   ```
2. Put the following content and save the file

   ```
   #!/bin/sh

   # check if script is executed for the interface we need
   if [ "$IFACE" != "p2p1" ]; then
       exit 0
   fi
   firewall-cmd --zone=trusted --change-interface="$IFACE"
   ```
3. Reboot
4. Verify

   ```
   $ sudo firewall-cmd --get-active-zones
   trusted
     interfaces: p2p1
   public
     interfaces: wlp1s0
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Assume X is the command (.e.g. `firewall-cmd --add-service=http` )

2 options :

- either `X --permanent` then `firewall-cmd --reload`
- OR run `X` (without permanaent) then run it again with permanent `X --permanent`